# Can I use an external HD with OS X as an internal boot disc?

Tags: hard-disk, osx

I installed OS X 10.12 on an external drive. I'd like to now swap the internal drive with the external drive. Will this work?

--- UPDATE

Thanks. for anyone else who is interested.

- OS X installed on an external will indeed work when added as an
  internal drive
- You CANNOT install Windows (via bootcamp) on an external drive
- A windows bootcamp installed on an internal drive cannot be booted when used as an external drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tech support question and will likely be closed, but to answer the question, it should work.  I have in the past run multiple OS's on external disks, then installed them into the chassis with no problem.  All that changes is the connection interface.